# Importing a 3rd party library into Angular2 /TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing a problem importing [this](https://github.com/psiphi75/ahrs) library into an Angular2/Ionic project. It is a library that does some calculations around raw accelerometer data. The example states I need to do a `require('ahrs')` which I'm trying to do in typescript. In the past, all I've needed to do was to copy over the js file to a directory which can be accessed and declare a variable for it. That approach works great for other libraries, but is error-ing here. Here is what I did:

Step 1: Copy the JS file to my project build directory via a custom copy.config

```
copyAHRS: {
        src: './external/www-ahrs.js',
        dest: '{{BUILD}}'
  },
```

This works fine - I can see www-ahrs.js in my build

Step 2: Include the file in my `index.html`

```
 <script src="build/www-ahrs.js"></script>
```

This works fine too.

Step 3: Try to use it in my code (in a component). This code is directly from the AHRS library [readme](https://github.com/psiphi75/ahrs#usage). This errors.

```
declare var ahrs:any;

    try {
              madgwick = new ahrs({
              sampleInterval: 20,
              algorithm: 'Madgwick',
              beta: 0.4,
              kp: 0.5,
              ki: 0
          }); 

      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log ("MADGWICK ERROR " + JSON.stringify(e))
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use npm to install it and then declare it at the top of your `*ts` file. Here's an example using `lodash`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
const _ = require('lodash');

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
```

Yours would be

```
const ahrs = require('ahrs');
```

Comment: Do I need to copy it to my build folder and include it with `<script src>` or do I do something else? If I do a require on top, it can't find it.

Comment: Ah never mind, instead of manually installing it, I installed it via `npm` and the require code worked perfectly! thanks!